# Emulator's Location screen shows blank. how to edit location?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, location

I am unable to edit location or set another location in my emulator. This shows me blank screen

[image: 1]

i have deleted Emulator many times also i have downloaded other API's emulator but still it shows me same blank screen in location section of emulator

Answer (score 1):

As seen from this bug report [click me](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228201899) you need to update the emulator version, this is the upgrade  [guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive)